# jquery beforeunload submit form

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a form.edit_recipe and my aim is to get this form to successfully save (if there is new data) before the page unloads, without the prompting of the user.

This is the critical bit of JQ:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
        if (auto_save_timer) {  // auto_save_timer == true means there are changes
          $("#auto_save_overlay").css('display', 'block');  // shows a spinner
          $(".edit_recipe").submit();
        }
      });
    });
```

On clicking a link to the next page, sometimes the changes save and sometimes they don't, even in identical situations and data sets.

I'm 99% certain my other variables and JQ on the page aren't effecting this, but I can update with more code samples if needs be.

I'm lost or what the issue is but I feel it's to do with the form data being interrupted by the next page loading.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:
Thanks for the suggestions so far. I think I should heed the advice of @see163 and perhaps consider forcing the user to manually press the save button and simply add an `alert()` if there are unsaved changes. Is this a more orthodox approach? And which JQuery events/actions should I use to be cross browser friendly if `.beforeunload` is rubbish in Opera and Chrome?

Comment: try calling .submit() before .css()

Comment: @maxhud Thank you for the suggestion, switching the `.css` and `.submit` seems to increase the rate at which this works but it still fails to save the changes sometimes. I'm hoping for the 'proper' way to do this, rather than polish for my poo.

Answer (score 1):

unload and beforeunload don't work in opera all time and in chrome sometimes.

Be careful.

Comment: Shouldn't this be an comment? It's not going to solve the issue.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13298/when-should-we-reply-with-a-comment-and-when-should-we-use-an-answer#13299

Comment: Or: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13298/when-should-we-reply-with-a-comment-and-when-should-we-use-an-answer#13302

Comment: you won (I didn't have enough karma for comments)

Comment: :) (To short, though very important comment.)

Answer (score 0):

On each link you could do:

```
<a href="javascript:submitForm('URL HERE')">............</a>
```

And then in your js do:

```
    function submitForm(url){
       if (auto_save_timer) {
          $("#auto_save_overlay").css('display', 'block');
          $(".edit_recipe").submit();
          window.location = url;
        }
    }
```